# Get response from PhanomJS server using the Requests library

Tags: javascript, python, phantomjs, python-requests

I am testing ways to use a PhantomJS server with Python's Requests library.

The GET and POST requests work as expected and I can get the PhantomJS server to request any page I want and put the results to the console, but I can not figure out how to send the page content back using `response.write(page.content)`. The request object has no `text`, `content` or usable `raw` content. The only way to get `response.write()` to work as expected is to hardcode the response content. If I add `keep-alive` to `true` the request functions hangs.

Here is my `server.js`

```
var webserver = require('webserver').create();
    page = require('webpage').create();

var service = webserver.listen(8080, function(request, response) {
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        console.log(request.post);
        var content = '';
        page.open(request.post, function (status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('FAIL to load the address');
                response.statusCode = 200;
                response.write('Page not responding.');
            } else {
                content = page.content;
                response.statusCode = 200;
                response.write(content);
            }
        })
    } else {
        response.statusCode = 200;
        console.log(request.method == 'GET' );
        response.write('No URL provided');
    }
    response.closeGracefully();
});
```

The Python code is straightforward:

```
import requests

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080, data='http://python.org')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection needs to be closed after sending data back: `response.close();`

Also I'd suggest using a variable in POST request, cause `response.post` is actually an object.

```
var webserver = require('webserver').create();
    page = require('webpage').create();

var service = webserver.listen(8080, function(request, response) {
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var url = request.post.url;
        console.log(url);
        var content = '';
        page.open(url, function (status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('FAIL to load the address');
                response.statusCode = 200;
                response.write('Page not responding.');
                response.close();
            } else {
                content = page.content;
                response.statusCode = 200;
                response.write(content);
                response.close();
            }
        })
    } else {
        response.statusCode = 200;
        console.log(request.method == 'GET' );
        response.write('No URL provided');
        respone.close();
    }

});
```

Then POST with url variable:

```
import requests
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080, data = {'url':'http://python.org'})
```

Comment: @dasdachs Please, mark as the answer if it's solved your problem )

Comment: it did, I just tested it and marked your answer. Thanks again!